# A job sequencing solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, vectors

I have written this code as a college assignment fot the famous [job sequencing problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/job-sequencing-problem/). Please tell me any improvements if possible. Oh, for `algorithms.h` header file, refer [my github repo](https://github.com/kesarling/cpp-projects/blob/master/algorithms.h)

The code:

```
#include "algorithms.h"

struct Job {
    int index = 0;
    int time_slot = 0;
    int profit = 0;
public:
    Job() = delete;
    explicit Job(int i, int time, int pr) {
        index = i;
        time_slot = time;
        profit = pr;
    }
    bool operator>=(Job j) {
        if ((this->time_slot == j.time_slot && this->profit >= j.profit) || (this->time_slot > j.time_slot)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool operator<=(Job j) {
        if ((this->time_slot == j.time_slot && this->profit <= j.profit) || (this->time_slot < j.time_slot)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool operator<(Job j) {
        if ((this->time_slot == j.time_slot && this->profit < j.profit) || (this->time_slot < j.time_slot)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool operator>(Job j) {
        if ((this->time_slot == j.time_slot && this->profit > j.profit) || (this->time_slot < j.time_slot)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool operator==(Job j) {
        if (this->time_slot == j.time_slot) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Job job) {
        out << job.index;
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    Job j1(1, 1, 3);
    Job j2(2, 3, 5);
    Job j3(3, 4, 20);
    Job j4(4, 3, 18);
    Job j5(5, 2, 1);
    Job j6(6, 1, 6);
    Job j7(7, 2, 30);
    std::vector<Job> vect = { j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7 };
    vect = Sorter<Job>::mergeSort(vect);
    auto order = [&]() {
        auto it = vect.begin();
        while (it + 1 != vect.end()) {
            if (*it == *(it + 1)) {
                it = vect.erase(it);
                continue;
            }
            it++;
        }
    };
    order();
    std::for_each(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](Job i) {std::cout << i << " "; });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer 1 minute 4 seconds after I posted it, but you may consider waiting for a couple of days to accept an answer.  This gives other reviewers the opportunity to see the question and provide their answers.

Comment: Okay. Sure :) I will keep this in mind henceforth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Job` class has public members, so it's simpler to make it an aggregate:

```
struct Job {
    int index;
    int time_slot;
    int profit;
};
```

Then, use `std::tie` to simplify the comparison operators: (operands to these operators should be marked as `const`, which you didn't)

```
bool operator<(const Job& lhs, const Job& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.time_slot, lhs.profit) < std::tie(rhs.time_slot, rhs.profit);
}

// implement other operators in terms of <
```

You `==` is not consistent with other comparison operators, which is confusing and likely to cause problems.

Also note that `if (condition) { return true; } return false;` should be changed to `return condition;` for clarity.

This is convoluted:

> ```
> Job j1(1, 1, 3);
> Job j2(2, 3, 5);
> Job j3(3, 4, 20);
> Job j4(4, 3, 18);
> Job j5(5, 2, 1);
> Job j6(6, 1, 6);
> Job j7(7, 2, 30);
> std::vector<Job> vect = { j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7 };
> ```

It should be simplified to

```
std::vector<Job> vect {
    {1, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, // ...
};
```

This:

> ```
> auto order = [&]() {
>     auto it = vect.begin();
>     while (it + 1 != vect.end()) {
>         if (*it == *(it + 1)) {
>             it = vect.erase(it);
>             continue;
>         }
>         it++;
>     }
> };
> order();
> ```

should be

```
vect.erase(std::unique(vect.begin(), vect.end()), vect.end());
```

(provided that I understand the code correctly).

And this:

> ```
> std::for_each(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](Job i) {std::cout << i << " "; });
> ```

is a complicated way of writing

```
for (const auto& job : vect) {
    std::cout << job << ' ';
}
```

or

```
std::copy(vect.begin(), vect.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<Job>{std::cout, ' '});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well, I tried the `std::unique` thing looking at the SO questions asked on it. It somehow doesn't work. I mean, it does not do what's expected. The problem is that it is not calling my overloaded operator. How do I go about this?

Comment: @cpplover `std::unique` should call the `==` associated with `Job`.  It is possible that failing to mark your `operator==` as `const` made `std::unique` unable to pick it up.  Anyway, you should not overload `==` just for the purpose of `std::unique` - pass a custom comparator instead.

Comment: @cpplover std::unique is calling your comparison function, the difference is in how it eliminates duplicates. Your `order()` handles consecutive duplicates by removing the _first_ duplicate, whereas `std::unique` will leave the first, and move any that _follow_ to the end of the list. So, when you use `std::unique` you get the same result in terms of `.time_slot` (1, 2, 3, 4), but the jobs retained are different. (Enhancing the `<<` operator to output the entire Job triple, not just the `.index` makes inspection easier.) You might be able to finesse your behavior with reverse iterators.

Comment: +1 for " if (condition) { return true; } return false; should be changed to return condition;".

Answer (score 3):

1. `public:` is excess in a `struct`.
2. Members directly initialized in ctors are better directly initialized:

```cpp
Job(int index, int time_slot, int profit)
    : index(index), time_slot(time_slot), profit(profit) {}
```

only more complex logic should go in ctor's body, if any.

3. As a matter of fact,

```cpp
    if(cond) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

is actually `return cond;`, indeed.

4. `this->` simply increases the code size without any additional benefits.

Comment: "explicit is excess for a ctor of arity greater than one." Actually no, `explicit` prevents copy-list-initialization.